# Как найти простое число? C#

Tags: c#

Дано число N. Найти первое простое число K, которое больше N и разница между ним и N делилась на 3. т.е. (K-N)/3=0

N = 130 000(сто тридцать тысяч)

Вывести найденное число на экран.

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации, добавьте описание конкретных проблем, с которыми вы столкнулись.

Answer (score 4):

Уточните ограничения задачи. При малом N можно написать например [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Решето_Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)

```
    int MaxF = 130045;
    int N = 7;
    if (N % 3 == 0){
       Console.WriteLine("Ищи дальше");
       return;
    }

    int [] a = new int[MaxF];
    for (int i=2;i<MaxF;i++)
        if (a[i] == 0){
            if (i > N && (i-N)%3 == 0){
                // Нашли
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                break;
            }
            for (int j=i+i;j<MaxF;j+=i)
                a[j] = 1;
        }
```

Comment: N = 100 000(сто тысяч). найти число К, большее N и разница между ним и К делится на 3 без остатка. и вывести найденное число на экран.

Comment: А что делает второй фор?

Comment: Если кратко, то помечает что число составное, если оно делится на i. Полностью в статье на Вики.

Answer (score 2):

Лови!:)

```
using System;

class NextPrime
{
    private static bool IsPrime(long n)
    {
        bool prime = n == 2 || ( n != 1 && n % 2 != 0 );

        for (long i = 3; prime && i * i <= n; i += 2 )
        {
            prime = n % i != 0;
        }

        return prime;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): ");

            int n;
            if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n) || n <= 0) break;

            long k = n;

            bool exists = false;
            while ( !( exists = IsPrime(k) ) && (k <= long.MaxValue - 3) ) k += 3;

            if (exists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "The closest prime number satisfied condition ( N - K ) % 3 == 0 is {0}\n",
                    k);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There is no such a prime integer number of type int\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 130000
The closest prime number satisfied condition ( N - K ) % 3 == 0 is 130003

Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

Можно ограничить время выполнения программы для такого курьезного значения, как 130002, заменив везде тип `long` на `int` для переменной `k` и в функции `IsPrime`.

Тогда вывод на консоль может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 130000
The closest prime number satisfied condition ( N - K ) % 3 == 0 is 130003

Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 130001
The closest prime number satisfied condition ( N - K ) % 3 == 0 is 130043

Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 130002
There is no such a prime integer number of type int

Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 130003
The closest prime number satisfied condition ( N - K ) % 3 == 0 is 130003

Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 130004
The closest prime number satisfied condition ( N - K ) % 3 == 0 is 130043

Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 130005
There is no such a prime integer number of type int

Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 130006
The closest prime number satisfied condition ( N - K ) % 3 == 0 is 130021

Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 130007
The closest prime number satisfied condition ( N - K ) % 3 == 0 is 130043

Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 130008
There is no such a prime integer number of type int

Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 130009
The closest prime number satisfied condition ( N - K ) % 3 == 0 is 130021

Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 130010
The closest prime number satisfied condition ( N - K ) % 3 == 0 is 130043

Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 130011
There is no such a prime integer number of type int

Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 130012
The closest prime number satisfied condition ( N - K ) % 3 == 0 is 130021

Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 130013
The closest prime number satisfied condition ( N - K ) % 3 == 0 is 130043

Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Забавно, что для числа 6 также нет такого простого числа, которое можно разместить в типе `Int32` и разность которого с 6 делилась бы нацело на 3.:)

```
Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 6
There is no such a prime integer number of type int

Eneter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0

Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Comment: @pavel  Это тяжелый случай. Но так как это не научный расчет, а учебная программа, то скорость выполнения программы для этого случая можно игнорировать.

Comment: Просто если N делится на 3, то и простое тоже делится на 3 (противоречие с простотой).

Comment: @pavel  Да, очевидно. Просто у меня сейчас голова другим забита.:)